# Unset relative date format for GTK Open/Save dialog

Tags: gtk

Is there a possibility to teach the GTK dialogs of my system, that they should not show 'Wednesday' for a files last-change date field, but instead always the concrete date in 'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM' form, or anything similar, which does not force me to calculate by myself which date the last change was?